# Disable next button until nsDialogs filled

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I am trying to create a datasource file in installation folder. I am using nsDialogs. Until the username and password are entered, Install/Next button shouldn't be enabled.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

Name database
OutFile database.exe

InstallDir $DESKTOP

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
Page custom pgPageCreate pgPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Var Dialog
Var TextUser
Var TextPass

Section /o "Data Source" datasource
    CreateDirectory "$INSTDIR\datasource"
    FileOpen $3 "$INSTDIR\datasource\datasource.properties" w
    FileWrite $3 username=$1$\n
    FileWrite $3 password=$2$\n
    FileClose $3
SectionEnd

Function pgPageCreate
    ${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${datasource}
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Database Settings" "Provide MySQL config details."

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 20% 26u 20% 10u "Username:"
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateText} 40% 24u 40% 12u ""
    Pop $TextUser

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 20% 62u 20% 10u "Password:"
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreatePassword} 40% 60u 40% 12u ""
    Pop $TextPass

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function PgPageLeave
    ${NSD_GetText} $TextUser $1
    ${NSD_GetText} $TextPass $2
FunctionEnd
```

[image]

How to disable this Install button. I couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the NSD_OnChange callback:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
#!include MUI2.nsh

Page Custom pgPageCreate pgPageLeave
Page InstFiles

Var hTextUser
Var hTextPass
Var User
Var Pass

Function OnLoginInfoChanged
Pop $0 ; Throw away handle we don't need
${NSD_GetText} $hTextUser $1
${NSD_GetText} $hTextPass $2
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 1 ; Get button handle
${If} "$1" == ""
${OrIf} "$2" == ""
    EnableWindow $0 0
${Else}
    EnableWindow $0 1
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function pgPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 40% 24u 40% 12u "$User"
Pop $hTextUser
${NSD_OnChange} $hTextUser OnLoginInfoChanged

${NSD_CreatePassword} 40% 60u 40% 12u "$Pass"
Pop $hTextPass
${NSD_OnChange} $hTextPass OnLoginInfoChanged

Push ""
Call OnLoginInfoChanged ; Simulate change event to initialize the button
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function PgPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $hTextUser $User
${NSD_GetText} $hTextPass $Pass
FunctionEnd

Section
DetailPrint $User:$Pass
SectionEnd
```